# configure apache2 to add user's path '/home/user'

Tags: apache2

I am new in ubuntu. I want to reach my index.html files in `/home/<user_name>`. Actualy I reach succesfully if I put them In `/var/www/html`and  typing the machine's IP address and port into the browser.

What must I modify to do this ? thank

Answer (score 0):

> Create a subfolder: `/home/user/www` and place there your site.

1. In `/etc/apache2/sites-available` create a file `mysite.conf` with contents:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mysite.local
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/site

    <Directory "/path/to/your/site">
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>    

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   ```
2. Create a symlink to enable the site:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf
   ```
3. Restart apache:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
4. Edit `/etc/hosts` and add:

   ```
   127.0.1.1    mysite.local
   ```

---

Now if you open in your web browser `http://mysite.local` you should see your index page, providing you have/created one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I do this, will I reach also the file in `var/www/html`?

Comment: Yes, it's a virtual server, you can create as many as you want.